# JQuery .slideUp() after time OR mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an element that is slided down by JQuery using `.slideDown()` method

```
$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideDown(800);
```

Now i want it to slide up after 6 seconds, but only if there is no hover on the element, if there is an hover, it should not `.slideUp()`.

So far i worked with a timeout that added `display:none` to the element while i was giving the element´s hover `display:block!important;` in CSS so it would not get `display: none` until the hover is over.

```
JS    
setTimeout(function () { 
        $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').css('display', 'none');
    }, 6000);

_______________________________________________________
CSS
    #dropdown_shopping_cart:hover {
        display: block!important;
    }
```

Now i want to add the `.slideUp()` to this.

Comment: Just check to see if the [mouse is still over the element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320190/without-jquery-i-need-to-find-out-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-not-determine), and if it is, do not trigger the `slideUp`

Comment: @Marcel W: check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the timeout on `mouseenter` and reset it on `mouseleave` like this:

```
var hide_div_to;

function hideDiv(){
    hide_div_to = setTimeout(function () { 
        $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideUp(800);
    }, 6000);
}

$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideDown(800,hideDiv());

$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').mouseenter(function(){
     clearTimeout(hide_div_to);
});

$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').mouseleave(function(){
     hideDiv();
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba6mnm3u/2/)

**UPDATE**

If you don't wan't to wait the timeout again when you leave, after the timeout is reached, you can do this:

```
$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideDown(800);

setTimeout(function () { 
    if(!$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').is(':hover')){
        $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideUp(800);
    }
    else{
        $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').mouseleave(function(){
            $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideUp(800);
        });
    }
}, 3000);
```

And here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba6mnm3u/6/) and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ba6mnm3u/7/) is another one that shows how this can be triggered multiple times.

Comment: I will update my answer with a working solution for this.

Comment: @MarcelW, i wrote same solution before Alvaro, not accepted mine :(

Comment: @kakajan @MarcelW , that's true. If you don't need to hide the shopping_cart inmediatly on mouseleave after the timeout @kakajan's answer should be the accepted one: he wrote it first and he used the `hover()` which I think is a more clever way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Check this:

```
var myVar;
myVar = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideUp(800)
}, 6000);


$("#dropdown_shopping_cart").hover(
    function() {
        clearTimeout(myVar);
    },

    function() {
        myVar = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideUp(800)
        }, 6000);
    }
);
```

By default shopping cart will `slideUp()` after 6 seconds, if mouse hover action occured, `setTimeOut` will be cleared, after mouse leave the shopping cart, `setTimeOut` will setted automatically

Answer (score 1):

Id suggest you work with mouseover and a class:

```
$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').hover(function(){
    if(!$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').hasClass('active'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
}, 
function() {
    var myVar = setTimeout(function() {
        if(!$('#dropdown_shopping_cart').hasClass('active'))
        {
            $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').slideUp()
        }
    }, 6000);
})
```

And than in your setTimeout Function you add:

Comment: `setTimeOut` will run once, if user hover after 6 seconds, and then leave the cart, `setTimeOut` will not run, `setTimeOut` must be initialized on each mouse leave

Comment: thanks, code got a bit obfuscated not, but this should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

> - **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yo5gnvy3/7/

```
 $('#dropdown_shopping_cart').hide().slideDown(800, function () {
     var events = $._data($(this)[0], "events") || {};
     if (events.mouseover === undefined) {
         $(this).delay(1000).slideUp()
     }
 });
```

Comment: This looked like something worth to try, but when I tried it in a JSFiddle it keeps saying `Cannot read property 'mouseover' of undefined`

Comment: @ Alvaro Flaño Larrondo: sorry, for the delay but i have found a better way. look the demo and let me know.

Comment: This doesn't look like what the SO was asking, or at least the alerts messages confused me a lot. I think I prefer my own answer.

Comment: Alvaro Flaño Larrondo : i was trying to make a demo that show both element with hover applied and element without hover. it is simple: if the element has no hover event attached it slideUp otherwise it stay. also i have cleaned up the OS code by putting hide() and slideDown() in chain and making the check only when the slideDown is finished. more clean and elegant IMHO.