# how to get top and left properties of offsetParent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As we can get offset top of an element by using like this:

```
$(selector).offset().top;
```

But how can we get the top value of parent offset div?

I've tried like this but doesn't work?

```
$(selector).offsetParent().top;
```

Comment: `$(selector).parent().offset().top;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, you can use like this:

```
$(selector).offsetParent().offset().top;
```

see documentation on [offsetParent](http://api.jquery.com/offsetparent/)

offsetParent doesn't get offset value but it just select  the closest **positioned** parent div. You can get the offset/position by using [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J4rDP/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent) like,

```
$(selector).parent().offset().top;
```

Read [Get position/offset of element relative to a parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634770/javascript-get-position-offset-of-element-relative-to-a-parent-container)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you have to go get offsets all the way to the topmost parent. If you have enough nested content it's probably worth writing a recursive function to get after it.