# Element's coordinates relative to its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

The method `el.getBoundingClientRect()` gives a result relative to the viewport's top-left corner (`0,0`), not relative to an element's parent, whereas `el.offsetTop`, `el.offsetLeft` (etc.) give a result relative to the parent.

What is the best practice to have the coordinates of an element relative to its parent? `el.getBoundingClientRect()` modified (how?) to use parent as `(0,0)` coordinate, or still `el.offsetTop`, `el.offsetLeft` and so on?

Comment: linked - https://stackoverflow.com/q/11634770/104380

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()`, simply subtracting the coordinates of the parent:

```
const parentPos = document.getElementById('parent-id').getBoundingClientRect();
const childPos  = document.getElementById('child-id').getBoundingClientRect();
const relativePos = {};

relativePos.top    = childPos.top - parentPos.top,
relativePos.right  = childPos.right - parentPos.right,
relativePos.bottom = childPos.bottom - parentPos.bottom,
relativePos.left   = childPos.left - parentPos.left;

console.log(relativePos);
// something like: {top: 50, right: -100, bottom: -50, left: 100}
```

Now you have the coordinates of the child relative to its parent.

Note that if the `top` or `left` coordinates are negative, it means that the child escapes its parent in that direction. Same if the `bottom` or `right` coordinates are positive.

#### Working example

```js
var parentPos = document.getElementById('parent-id').getBoundingClientRect(),
    childPos = document.getElementById('child-id').getBoundingClientRect(),
    relativePos = {};

relativePos.top = childPos.top - parentPos.top,
relativePos.right = childPos.right - parentPos.right,
relativePos.bottom = childPos.bottom - parentPos.bottom,
relativePos.left = childPos.left - parentPos.left;

console.log(relativePos);
```

```css
#parent-id {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: grey;
}

#child-id {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-id">
    <div id="child-id"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not account for CSS transforms.

Comment: I meant, if there are 3D transforms between parent and child, this does not work. It will be the difference in document space, but not relative to the parent in parent space.

Comment: This worked for me in another context, but you may have to do "relativePos.right = childPos.right - parentPos.left", if you want the position relative to the top/left. Same for .left.

Comment: It will probably also not work if the parent has a scroll :(

Comment: doesn't work, the parent's borders & paddings shifted the result

Comment: Also won't work if parent has display: contents. You'd have to take the parent of that parent.