# Difference between $(this).position and getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery provide `position` function which has top and left value.
Either vanilla javascript has `getBoundingClientRect()`

I don't the difference between them.
When I checked, it's value difference.

getBoundingClientRect()
[image]

How can I convert jQuery's `position` to `getBoundingClientRect`.
As you see, x is 236, but left is 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery .position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) gets position relative to the parent.
From documentation: Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

[getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) - relative to the window.
From documentation: The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

The solution found here: [Element's coordinates relative to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423335/elements-coordinates-relative-to-its-parent/26423749#26423749)