# Javascript HTML: how to get element's position relative to its parent?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get the element's position (left & top) relative to its parent?

Note: the parent `position` is neither `relative` nor `absolute`, so `offsetLeft` & `offsetTop` wouldn't work.

The parent/child might have margins/borders/paddings.

Vanilla JS only, no jquery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element's coordinates relative to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423335/elements-coordinates-relative-to-its-parent)

Comment: No. The solution works only if the parent has no border. If does, the result shifted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.getBoundingClientRect()` which returns position of the element relative to the viewport. So you can get position of both the element and the parent using `.getBoundingClientRect()` and calculate the elements position relative to parent from it. Check out the following answer.

[Element's coordinates relative to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26423749/13307423)

Comment: is that calculates automatically for the parent's margin/border/padding ?

Comment: It calculates height/width = height/width + padding. Checkout the documentation. 
[Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: i tested (clientRect.top - parentRect.top) only works for parent without borders & paddings. The width of borders & paddings shifted the result. Yes i can fetch the border/padding width. Is there a more simple way?

Comment: update: the child's borders & paddings are shifting the result too

Answer (score 0):

You can get the style via window.getComputedStyle and vanilla js selectors.

```js
function getStyleProp(elem, prop){
    if(window.getComputedStyle)
        return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    else if(elem.currentStyle) return elem.currentStyle[prop]; //IE
}


elem = document.getElementById("id")
console.log(getStyleProp(elem, "top"))
console.log(getStyleProp(elem, "left"))
```

Original function written by [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w)

src: [Read CSS property of an element using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894577/read-css-property-of-an-element-using-javascript)