# Why setting scrollLeft and scrollTop on mousemove results in max scroll* unexpectedly early?

Tags: javascript, html, math, coordinates, mousemove

In answering [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850926/how-to-get-a-div-to-scroll-any-direction-by-hovering-on-child-div), I posted what was supposed to be a simple demo showing how to achieve movement of a child `<div>` relative to the movement of the cursor within its parent `<div>`, by the manipulation of [`element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and [`element.scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft).

My demo basically works as expected, demonstrating the basics of gathering the cursor coordinates on [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) via [`event.pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) and [`event.pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY), doing a little math to calculate the ratio by which the larger `.inner` child should be moved, and applying the `scroll*`.

**However**, I noticed that when moving my cursor near to the bottom and/or right of the `.outer` parent, the `.inner` child would be scrolled to its maximum ahead of my cursor reaching the edge(s).

**What have I done to find a solution?**
Realising that `event.pageX` would always be at least `1` and never more than `1` less than the `width` and that `event.pageY` would never be more than `1` less of the parent `<div>`'s `height`, I added a rudimentary function to expand the coordinate range from `0` to the full `width` and/or `height`.
Although the function does its job, it didn't cure the premature maximum `scroll*`.

**EDIT**: I had not tested this code outside SO snippets which appear to present the HTML differently depending on if it's being edited, viewed normally or expanded; Sometimes the function is *required*, and sometimes it's presence results in negative values.

> `scrollTop` doesn't respond to negative values; instead, it sets itself back to `0`.
>
> If set to a value greater than the maximum available for the element, `scrollTop` settles itself to the maximum value.

The same is true for `scrollLeft`.
So this inconsistency isn't relevant; the problem was evident before I added the function.

**What else?**
I have repeatedly checked the math and, *e.g.*

- Say we have a parent `<div>` measuring `100px` by `100px`
- And a child`<div>` measuring `300px` by `300px` ( 3 times the parent on both axes)
- If the cursor is at coord. `{ x: 90, y: 90 }`
- The `scrollTop` should be set to `90 * 3` = `270`
- And `scrollLeft` should be set to `90 * 3` = `270`
- So the child `<div>`'s bottom or right edges should **not** be aligned with those of the parent.

With that in mind, as I say, I have checked and checked again, and the math **should** work, but the result is unexpected.

**Here's the code**, with some extra bits outputting some of the the numbers in `innerHTML` (the console gets in the way a bit otherwise), and my question will continue under it. The extra `<output>` UI doesn't affect the result.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll( "div" ),
      outer_div = divs[ 0 ],
      outer_div_styles = window.getComputedStyle( outer_div ),
      inner_div_styles = window.getComputedStyle( divs[ 1 ] ),
      outer_div_width = parseInt( outer_div_styles.width ),
      outer_div_height = parseInt( outer_div_styles.height ),
      dimention_ratio = {
        x: parseInt( inner_div_styles.width ) / outer_div_width,
        y: parseInt( inner_div_styles.height ) / outer_div_height
      },
      half_odw = outer_div_width / 2,
      half_odh = outer_div_height / 2,
      expandCoords = function( e ) { // sometimes useful, never harmful
        var X = e.pageX,
            Y = e.pageY;
        if ( X < half_odw ) {
          X -= 1;
        } else if ( X > half_odw ) {
          X += 1;
        }
        if ( Y < half_odh ) {
          Y -= 1;
        } else if ( Y > half_odh ) {
          Y += 1;
        }
        return { x: X, y: Y };
      },
      // for demo convenience
      output = document.querySelector( "output" );
outer_div.addEventListener( "mousemove", function( evt ) {
  evt = expandCoords( evt );
  // for demo convenience
  output.innerHTML = "Coords: x:" + evt.x + ", y:" + evt.y + "<br>" +
                     "scrollLeft = " + ( evt.x * dimention_ratio.x ) + "<br>" +
                     "scrollTop = " + ( evt.y * dimention_ratio.y );
  outer_div.scrollLeft = evt.x * dimention_ratio.x;
  outer_div.scrollTop = evt.y * dimention_ratio.y;
}, false );
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
.outer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  width: 1000vw; /* 10 times the width of its parent */
  height: 500vh; /* 5 times the height of its parent */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 20px green; /* no border edge highlight */
  background: radial-gradient( white, black );
}

/* for demo convenience */
output {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 10vw;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  background: white;
  padding: .2em .4em .3em;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div><output></output></div>
```

As you should see, the right and bottom edge(s) of the child `<div>` come into view long before the cursor reaches the right and/or bottom edge(s) of the parent.

**Why is this, and how can it be fixed in a dynamic application?**

By *"dynamic application"* I mean without hard coding the solution on a case by case basis.

**NOTE**: Although (I know) this code can be *optimized* in many ways, it is purely for demonstration and thus, optimisations that do not affect a fix for the specific problem are not of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I figured it out

`scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` are the measure of how many pixels are scrolled on their respective axes.
This equates to how much is scrolled **out of view**, so there is always an amount remaining that cannot be scrolled.
This amount is equal to the respective measure of the parent.

- If the child `<div>` is twice the size of the parent, then when scrolled to its maximum on either axes, only half will be scrolled.
- If the child is three times the size, at max scroll, two thirds will be scrolled.
- `10` times the size: `9/10ths` scrolled *etc.*

In this particular application, the cursor coordinates should be multiplied by the dimension ratios calculated as:

`( width of the child minus the width of the parent ) divided by the width of the parent`
and
`( height of the child minus the height of the parent ) divided by the height of the parent`

### So the corrected code, handling arbitrary ratios:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll( "div" ),
      outer_div = divs[ 0 ],
      outer_div_styles = window.getComputedStyle( outer_div ),
      inner_div_styles = window.getComputedStyle( divs[ 1 ] ),
      outer_div_width = parseInt( outer_div_styles.width ),
      outer_div_height = parseInt( outer_div_styles.height ),
      dimention_ratio = {
        x: ( parseInt( inner_div_styles.width ) - outer_div_width ) / outer_div_width, // fixed
        y: ( parseInt( inner_div_styles.height ) - outer_div_height ) / outer_div_height // fixed
      },
      half_odw = outer_div_width / 2,
      half_odh = outer_div_height / 2,
      expandCoords = function( e ) {
        var X = e.pageX,
            Y = e.pageY;
        if ( X < half_odw ) {
          X -= 1;
        } else if ( X > half_odw ) {
          X += 1;
        }
        if ( Y < half_odh ) {
          Y -= 1;
        } else if ( Y > half_odh ) {
          Y += 1;
        }
        return { x: X, y: Y };
      };
outer_div.addEventListener( "mousemove", function( evt ) {
  evt = expandCoords( evt );
  outer_div.scrollLeft = evt.x * dimention_ratio.x;
  outer_div.scrollTop = evt.y * dimention_ratio.y;
}, false );
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
.outer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  width: 1234vw; /* 12.34 times the width of its parent */
  height: 567vh; /* 5.67 times the height of its parent */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 20px green; /* no border edge highlight */
  background: radial-gradient( white, black );
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```