# How to know element is outside the boundary of main parent element in angularjs 2 (Not direct parent)

Tags: angular

```
<div class="nodelevel1">

<div class="nodelevel2">

<div class="nodelevel3">

<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

I want to know if **item** element is outside the boundary of  **nodelevel1** element when it render on browser and i want to get its **top and left position** relative to **nodelevel1**

Answer (score 0):

This is a start on a solution, getting the position of a child element relative to its immediate parent:

[Get position/offset of element relative to a parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634770/get-position-offset-of-element-relative-to-a-parent-container)

Iterate that over two more levels of parents, and you'll have the position of `item` relative to `nodelevel1`.

Then do the math on the bounding rects to see if the bounding rect of `item` spills outside of the bounding rect of `nodelevel1`.

Comment: I need it in angularjs 2 and i do not want directly parent i want Item position relative to nodelevel1 element