# JS get available space between text and element boundaries

Tags: javascript, material-design

Is there a way to get available space between text and element boundaries?

The problem is next. I need to display an error message in input label (by design). If there is not enough space I need to show an Icon that can be hovered and display an error.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: PD - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634770/get-position-offset-of-element-relative-to-a-parent-container

Comment: where's your attempt so far ?

Comment: That won't work

Comment: @ths how can one attempt when not having means for that? I'm asking exactly for these.

Comment: at least show us the `HTML` structure so we could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @ths any input from here https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples

Comment: And since I use their component both for label and error message I can't rely on its container size, because it will grow with text

Answer (score 0):

So if this is your element:

```
<div style="width:500px;" id="d">Birth settlement</div>
```

Put the text inside a span and calculate *parent length - child length*.

```js
document.getElementById('l').textContent = document.getElementById('d').offsetWidth - document.getElementById('s').offsetWidth;
```

```html
<div style="width:500px;" id="d"><span id="s">Birth settlement</span></div>
<span id="l"></span>
```

Comment: The problem here is that `Birth settlement` will contain an error and this will affect the result. That's why I asked about text and not element

Comment: I don't understand. My snippet gives you the width of the text.

Comment: Your text is fixed sized meanwhile mine may already contain an error. Inside the same tag.