# CSS: Load SVG and position relative to its elements

Tags: html, css, svg, css-position, background-image

In the spirit of http://www.csszengarden.com/,
I want to see how far I can go with css only in this situation.

I am given an html page with the following list which I can style however I want using a css file, but not modify. The text of the items is not known in advance.

```html
<ul>
    <li id="item1">You</li>
    <li id="item2">Can</li>
    <li id="item3">Call</li>
    <li id="item4">Me</li>
    <li id="item5">Al</li>
</ul>
```

I also have this separate SVG file ([view in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bduy4j0v/)):

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 800 600" enable-background="new 0 0 800 600" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="22" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M64.5,381.5c232-235,365-321,335-152
    s-152,145-101,1s265-105,241-5s-68,342-159,258s142-211,164-70s191-83,191-83"/>
<circle id="circle1" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="22" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="131" cy="323" r="23"/>
<circle id="circle2" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="22" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="290" cy="288" r="23"/>
<circle id="circle3" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="22" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="528" cy="272" r="23"/>
<circle id="circle4" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="22" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="383" cy="487" r="23"/>
<circle id="circle5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="22" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="698" cy="375" r="23"/>
</svg>
```

In my CSS file, I want to load the SVG and style the list like so:
[each text on a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCl3z.png)

Basically, positioning `#item1` relative to `#circle1`, `#item2` relative to `#circle2` and so on
(truly relative, without hardcoding the item positions).

I haven't found a way to both load an SVG and have its elements accessible only via CSS. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, CSS doesn't allow referencing dynamic properties like positions from unrelated elements.

You can achieve that with JavaScript:

1. First, [check the relative position of each `circle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634770/get-position-offset-of-element-relative-to-a-parent-container)

```js
const circle1 = document.querySelector('#circle1');
const { offsetLeft, offsetTop } = circle1;
```

2. Then, set those coordinates to the `top` and `left` values of these offsets:

```js
const label1 = document.querySelector('#item1');
label1.style.position = 'absolute';
label1.style.left = `${offsetLeft}px`;
label1.style.top = `${offsetTop}px`;
```

In case getting the offset doesn't work with plain JS and your SVG, consider using a 3rd party library (like jQuery) or reading the `cx` and `cy` attributes directly from the `<circle>` element.