# Creating a side panel similar to code pen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, draggable, framer-motion

I am trying to create a side panel similar to that of codepen editor in react, where you can drag to adjust the size of the different editors.

[image: Codepen example]

If I drag an editor header towards the bottom low enough, the editor below it will follow, almost as if I have appended that component to the drag, likewise if i try ti drag the header upwards. I have built the layout to my liking with a similar concept to the accordion from material UI:

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-accordion/

I was also able to mimic the on click behaviors of the header from codepen, for example, double click would open the editor to full size and triple click will open all evenly by keeping track of the heights of all the 'containers' in a useState hook. However, I am having trouble with the dragging part. I am looking for some suggestions for good libraries/ideas to use to help me achieve this.

Currently I am using framer motion to make the expanding of the container more 'smooth'.

https://www.framer.com/docs/transition/

I noticed that they also have dragging capabilities which I am also exploring. My idea is to have an onDrag for each of the headers. Depending on which header I am dragging, if I drag down until my container size is 0, I start shrinking the container below it and then the one below it and so on and so forth. I am able to get the Y property from the onDrag function but I am a bit hesitant to do my calculations in x/y coordinates. Does anyone have any suggestions or any libraries that might make this easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know any libraries. I think if you got this far you can probably do it yourself in plain js, using listeners and selectors, etc, or whatever react can provide. Is there something specific that makes you ‘hesitant’? I recently found these which made things easier for me, they might not be 100% relevant but still good to know: getBoundingClientRect
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
That will tell the position relative to the viewport, it was useful for me dragging dividers between panels.
And if you need the position relative to the container:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634823/5350539
And if you’re not already, I guess you could look at setting the panel CSS positions using ‘bottom’ (with position absolute or relative),  then animating the height to e.g. 30px less than the bottom edge of the upper panel. Tip: while dragging, add a body class to disable user select: user-select: none;